# Symmetrical uncertainty

Tags: feature-selection

I want to implement a filter algorithm for dimension reduction using symmetrical uncertain. I do not know how to write mathematical equation containing probability.
e.g. `H(x)=-p(x)*log2(P(x))` Like that there are so many equation.

please tell me how to write this type of equation.

Comment: Symmetrical Uncertainty is defined as `U(X,Y)=2*I(X;Y)/(H(X)+H(Y))` where `I(X;Y)` is the Mutual Information. What else do you want to know ?

Comment: There is a sample project written in python : https://github.com/shiralkarprashant/FCBF

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [ITMO_FS](https://pypi.org/project/ITMO-FS) library, which contains different filters, wrappers, hybrids, and embedded feature selection techniques including symmetrical uncertainty.

Comment: Which of the algorithms corresponds to Weight by Uncertainty ?

Comment: @DeGninou it's filters.univariate.su_measure(X, y)